# EPPlus ASP.NET Excel sheet is blank when downloaded

Tags: asp.net, excel, epplus

I'm trying to make an Excel spreadsheet using ASP.NET and the spreadsheet has nothing in it.  I know my datatable is full.  It's has bytes associated with the object just the end result is blank.

```
                DataTable dt = sql.GetSqlTable(Query);
                using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
                {
                    ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Worksheet.xlsx");
                    ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);
                    var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                    pck.SaveAs(ms);
                    ms.Position = 0;
                    ms.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                }
```

Comment: If you look at the file in a text editor, do you see any text content at the beginning or end? How did you verify the datatable has data?

Comment: The above snippet works. I get an Excel with data. Are you sure the query returns any results?

Comment: Not sure what changed but when I went into work and tried again it worked.  Hate those issues

Comment: You got a blank page or a blank excel file?  Did you set the content type?

Comment: I have been experiencing a similar issue. When I download the file and open it in excel it opens up blank. If you open and repair the data is there.